# How can I remove the "!NEW" marker that appears next to items in SQL Server Reporting Services 2005's Report Manager Web interface?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Like many others, I have had to resort to writing a custom report deployer for SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services elements.

Currently, its method is to completely destroy the entire contents of the entire report server, then to re-upload all RDLs, images, etc. from scratch.  (This may need to change one day if we start using SSRS more deeply, but it's effective for now.)

The most obvious user-visible drawback to this approach is that, every time I redeploy, every single item on the report server gets one of those little green image badges that says "!NEW" next to it.

We can live with this, I guess, but it's cluttery and annoying . . . does anyone know a way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure you can.

But you could always make the "new!" white.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345247.aspx